# ¿Como guardar los estilos que aplico desde un botón a una tabla sin que se pierdan al recargar?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Espero esten bien. Estoy tratando de guardar un estilo en una tabla que se carga consultando una base de datos, con un boton al dejar presionado hago que la fila cambia de color, pero quiero que ese color permanezca en la tabla al recargar la pagina. Me gustaria saber si hay una forma de guardar esos estilos para que al momento de recargar la pagina no se pierdan si no que permanezcan pero no se si lo estoy haciendo de la forma correcta o puedo intentar hacer otra cosa.

[image: Dejo presionado el boton de pendiente y se colorea la fila, pero al recargar la pagina pierdo el estilo]

Este es el codigo donde se carga la tabla, añado una clase al `<tr>` que es cambiada por medio de Js.

```html
<?php if($query->num_rows>0):?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
    <th class="text-center">CR</th>
    <th class="text-center">Tienda</th>
    <th class="text-center">Descripcion</th>
    <th class="text-center">Fecha</th>
    <th class="text-center">Tecnico</th>
    <th></th>
</thead>


<?php 
    //$bgRowTabla = '';
    

    while ($r=$query->fetch_array()): ?>

    
    
    
<tr class="" id="tabla-fila-<?php echo $r["id"];?>">
    <td><?php echo $r["cr"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["tienda"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["descripcion"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["fecha"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $r["tecnico"]; ?></td>
    <td style="width:250px;">
        <a data-id="<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-edit btn-sm btn-warning">Editar</a>
        <a href="#" id="del-<?php echo $r["id"];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Eliminar</a>
        <div class="btn btnRealizado" id="btnClick-<?php echo $r["id"];?>" oncontextmenu="return false">Pendiente</div> 
    </script>

    </td>
</tr>

    <?php endwhile;?>

</table>
```

Este el script que uso dentro del while:
La pagina al recargarse establece el valor de la variable `classRow` en 0, al presionar el boton le da el valor de `success` que por medio de bootstrap pinta la fila en verde.

```html
<script>

        
//Script para el boton pendiente


var btnClick = document.getElementById('btnClick-<?php echo $r["id"];?>');
var startTime, endTime;

var classRow =  0;
$('#tabla-fila-<?php echo $r["id"];?>').addClass(classRow);

    /*Cuando se haga clic*/
    btnClick.onmousedown = function() {
    startTime = new Date();
    console.log("Estoy presionado, haz lo que necesites...");
    numBtnclick = event.button;
    };

    /*Cuando se deje de hacer clic*/
    
    btnClick.onmouseup = function() {
    btnClick = document.getElementById('btnClick-<?php echo $r["id"];?>');
    
    endTime = new Date();
    var timeDiff = endTime - startTime; //en ms
    
    if(timeDiff > 621 && numBtnclick !== 2){

            btnClick.style.backgroundColor = "greenyellow";
            btnClick.innerHTML = "Realizado";
            btnClick.style.color = "green";
            
            //$('#tabla-fila-<?php echo $r["id"];?>').removeClass(classRow);
            
            var classRow = 'success';   
            
            $('#tabla-fila-<?php echo $r["id"];?>').addClass(classRow);
                //  loadTabla();


    }
    
    console.log("Se hizo clic:\n" + startTime);
    console.log("Se levantó el clic:\n" + endTime);
    console.log("Tiempo transcurrido:\n" + timeDiff + " ms");
    
    };

</script>
```

Gracias de antemano, saludos.
Brayan

Comment: Dentro de tu tabla de base de datos deberías agregar una columna extray puedes llamarla "Realizado" puede ser de tipo "bit", al momento de darle clic al bóton, ademas de modificar los colores del elemento HTML tienes que agregar una llamada a la base de datos para que modifique el valor de la columna antes mencionada. al momento de inicializar tu tabla toma en consideración la nueva columna para identificar de que color se pintara, por ejemplo si el valor es "1" puedes agregarle que se pinte verde y si es "0" no hacerlo.

Comment: Genial, aplicaré esa idea, muchísimas gracias!